# создать БД из файла

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь выбрать файл и на основе выбранного файла создать БД.
Android 11

Выбор БД:

```
private val loadContent =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
            uri?.takeIf { it.toString().contains(".db", true) }?.let {
                App.instance.settingsRepository.setDatabaseUri(it)
                startApp()
            } ?: run {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Файл не выбран", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

Попытка создания:

```
private val db: Database by lazy {
        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(this.applicationContext, Database::class.java, databaseName)
            .apply {
                if (!settingsRepository.getCreateStatus()) {
                    createFromFile(
                        PathCompatUtil.getFilePath(uri = settingsRepository.getDatabaseUri()!!).toFile()!!
                    )
                }
            }
            .build()

        settingsRepository.setCreateStatus(true)
        db
    }
```

PathCompatUtil

```
fun String?.toFile(): File? = this?.let { File(it) }

@Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection")
object PathCompatUtil {

    @WorkerThread
    fun getFilePath(context: Context = App.instance, uri: Uri): String? = context.run {
        return try {
            when {
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT -> getDataColumn(uri, null, null)
                else -> getPathKitkatPlus(uri)
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            null
        }
    }


    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi", "DefaultLocale")
    private fun Context.getPathKitkatPlus(uri: Uri): String? {
        when {
            DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(applicationContext, uri) -> {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                when {
                    uri.isExternalStorageDocument -> {
                        val parts = docId.split(":")
                        if ("primary".equals(parts[0], true)) {
                            return "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/${parts[1]}"
                        }
                    }
                    uri.isDownloadsDocument -> {
                        val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                            docId.toLong()
                        )
                        return getDataColumn(contentUri, null, null)
                    }
                    uri.isMediaDocument -> {
                        val parts = docId.split(":")
                        val contentUri = when (parts[0].toLowerCase()) {
                            "image" -> MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                            "video" -> MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                            "audio" -> MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                            else -> return null
                        }
                        return getDataColumn(contentUri, "_id=?", arrayOf(parts[1]))
                    }
                }
            }
            "content".equals(uri.scheme, true) -> {
                return if (uri.isGooglePhotosUri) {
                    uri.lastPathSegment
                } else {
                    getDataColumn(uri, null, null)
                }
            }
            "file".equals(uri.scheme, true) -> {
                return uri.path
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun Context.getDataColumn(uri: Uri, selection: String?, args: Array<String>?): String? {
        contentResolver?.query(uri, arrayOf("_data"), selection, args, null)?.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                return it.getString(it.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data"))
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    private val Uri.isExternalStorageDocument: Boolean
        get() = authority == "com.android.externalstorage.documents"

    private val Uri.isDownloadsDocument: Boolean
        get() = authority == "com.android.providers.downloads.documents"

    private val Uri.isMediaDocument: Boolean
        get() = authority == "com.android.providers.media.documents"

    private val Uri.isGooglePhotosUri: Boolean
        get() = authority == "com.google.android.apps.photos.content"
}
```

Но происходит исключение

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to copy database file.   Caused
> by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/Download/base.db: open failed: EACCES (Permission
> denied) Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES
> (Permission denied)

Как можно решить? Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы нашел тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/3671076

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

private void requestPermission() {
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
        }
    } else {
        //below android 11
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PermissionActivity.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

clickistener = {
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && !Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
       requestPermission()
       return
    }
    chooseFile()
}
```